# TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callableon mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, discord.py

I have been trying to create a warn system using mongodb, and I am having a hard time setting up the schema/ section to upload each time a user gets warned. the error I get is what is below. I have looked around all documentation I can, I just do not understand.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dargo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dargo\PycharmProjects\MaxCodezBot\cogs\warns.py", line 53, in warn
    await self.client.warns.insert(warn)
  File "C:\Users\dargo\PycharmProjects\MaxCodezBot\utils\mongo.py", line 85, in insert
    await self.db.insert_one(dict)
  File "C:\Users\dargo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 3440, in __call__
    raise TypeError("'Collection' object is not callable. If you "
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert_one' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

with the code

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    # @commands.has_guild_permissions(kick_members=True)
    async def warn(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason=None):
        if user is None:
            await ctx.send("You have not provided a user!")
            return

        if user is user.bot:
            await ctx.send(f"<@{ctx.author.id}, you cannot warn a bot!")
            return

        if user.id == ctx.author.id:
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"<@{ctx.author.id}>, you are not allowed to warn yourself!")

            embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.guild.name} Custom Designed Bot")
            embed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at

            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

        author_id = ctx.author.id
        guild = ctx.message.guild.id
        first_warning = False
        warn_id = 0
        reason = reason or None

        warn = {
            "_id": ctx.message.guild.id,
            "user": user.id,
            "warn": [{
                "PunishType": 'warn',
                "Moderator": ctx.message.author.id,
                "Reason": reason,
            }],
        }
        await self.client.warns.insert(warn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the code and error trace I believe.

Error is at `self.db.insert_one(dict)`

It means that you are trying to invoke `insert one` on `db` object.

It should be `db.coll.insert_one(doc)`

Comment: yes I updated it with that code, I now get NameError: name 'db' is not defined, actually I checked on mongodb, and it created another database and the collection with it, then pasted the warn in there but not in the database I wanted

Comment: It's strange. It should not print the error which is not related to the code

Comment: yes cause when i switched to the code you gave me, it created a collection within my database. but when I tried to issue another warn it didn't add another object aka the warn

Comment: ok so i managed to get it to write to the database, but when I try to give it another warning, it doesn't add another object/array for the new warning

Comment: any assistance,

Comment: You need to use `$push` as it is an array. You cannot simply insert. You need to update

Comment: I am using the $push and it is still only updating the first warning with the the code, basically it doesn't add another object for the new warning just updates the first object aka the first warning, but I looked it up and it needs $push not "$push" but it wont allow me to do $push ` `if _id is None:             await self.bot.warns.upsert(warn)         elif user.id in data:             await self.bot.warns.update_one({"_id": user.id}, {                 "$push": {"warn": [{"PunishType": "warn", "Moderator": ctx.message.author.id, "Reason": reason}]}})`

Comment: I would suggest you to open another question.